# Image tags in labels with "for" don't respond to clicks in IE7

Tags: html, internet-explorer, label

In a simple setup with an image inside a label:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='x'>
<label for='x'>click me <img src='http://placedog.com/20/20'></label>
```

clicks on the image control the checkbox just like clicks on the text in the label or clicks on the checkbox itself, in *most* browsers. That it doesn't work in IE7 doesn't particularly surprise me, but I'm wondering whether there's some weird IE way of *making* it work, in that browser.

*fake edit* hmm apparently it doesn't work in IE8 either.

Comment: Have you tried putting the label before the input, to see if that has any effect?

Comment: Well the text of the label works fine; it's just the `<img>` that doesn't respond to clicks. And I really do want the label to follow the input.  (I tried it in the jsfiddle and it didn't work anyway :-)

Comment: A quick bit of googling tells me that this has been a problem since at least 2005: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/using_images_as he does provide an update towards the end for doing this in three lines of JQuery though.

Comment: Right, thanks for the link; I couldn't find a reference. It is indeed easy to repair with jQuery, but it's stupid that it's necessary :-) Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is stupid! Perhaps submit a bug report to the developers. It's a long shot, but maybe they'll fix it!

Comment: They won't fix an IE7 bug like this unless they're crazy :-)  I'll add a jQuery answer if nobody else does.

Comment: That's a good point :P I've added an answer that's essentially what I referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, IE doesn't like this idea. The only way to get around it is with a bit of Javascript - here's an example using JQuery.

```
$("label img").live("click", function() {
   $("#" + $(this).parents("label").attr("for")).click();
});
```

See http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/using_images_as for a discussion on this.

Answer (score 1):

A little rough and ready, but works without JQuery...

```
<p>
   <input type="radio" id="rb1" value="rb1" />
   <label for="rb1">
       <img src="image1.png"
            onclick="try{document.getElementById('rb1').checked=true;}catch(e){};return true;" />
   </label>
</p>
<p>
   <input type="radio" id="rb2" value="rb2" />
   <label for="rb2">
       <img src="image2.png"
            onclick="try{document.getElementById('rb2').checked=true;}catch(e){};return true;" />
   </label>
</p>
```

Could be improved,  but is fairly resilient as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could put an absolutely positioned div spanning the whole width and height of the label. Note though that you have to use IE's opacity filter to make the cover div invisible, because  with visibility: hidden it is completely ignored by IE7 and 8.

```
<style>
.cover{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>

<label>
  <div class="cover"></div>
  <img src="img.png" alt="img" />
</label>
```